# How to calculate the perimeter of the polygon using python programming

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to calculate the perimeter of each feature of the polygon?

For calculating the area we are using:

```
area=feature.geometry().area()
```

is there any function to calculate the circumference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

similar to .area(), you can use .length() . For a polygon it yields the perimeter.

```
perimeter=feature.geometry().length()
```